# How do python libraries work when calling a python script from C++?

Tags: python, c++, embedding

I'd like to know how i can include the imported libraries from a python file when calling it from C++ code.

So far i managed to call a basic python script from my C++ code.

```
#include <Python/Python.h>

Py_Initialize();
FILE *fd = fopen("/path/Test.py", "r");
PyRun_SimpleFileEx(fd, "/path/Test.py", 1);
```

so i was wondering how libraries in the python file will be dealt with when compiling my C++ program.

As i understand the C++ code calls a python interpreter that is able to execute the python script. So i guess the interpreter should have some knowledge about the libraries. Is it done with linking? Help and additional info would be appreciated!

Comment: What you do in `PyRun_SimpleFileEx()` is nothing else as running a full-featured Python interpreter. AFAIK, it can do the same as a Python interpreter started from command line. This includes as well import of Python libraries. (I believe we've already done this in our application.)

Comment: _Is it done with linking?_ Ahem... Python is an interpreter. When it imports a library it reads a file (which has to be locatable by the Python interpreter at that specific time point). This doesn't change if you run the interpreter out of a compiled C++ program. The trick is to setup the Python interpreter with the appropriate path. In our case, we deploy Python code together with our executable and DLLs. At runtime, we determine the binary path of the executable, construct the proper Python lib. path from this, and provide the appropriate code to Python.

Comment: Please, don't forget that there are also functions where Python code can be provided as `string`. So, you can embed Python code as text in your C++ code as well as build Python code on the fly from snippets and text which is determined at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. This was really helpful!